# Am I thinking about and using singleton types in Haskell correctly?

Tags: haskell, singleton

I want to create several incompatible, but otherwise equal, datatypes. That is, I'd like to have a parameterized type `Foo a`, and functions such as

```
bar :: (Foo a) -> (Foo a) -> (Foo a)
```

*without actually caring* about what `a` is. To clarify further, I'd like the type system to stop me from doing

```
x :: Foo Int
y :: Foo Char
bar x y
```

while I at the same time don't really care about `Int` and `Char` (I only care that they're not the same).

In my actual code I have a type for polynomials over a given ring. I don't actually care what the indeterminates are, as long as the type system stops me from adding a polynomial in t with a polynomial in s. So far I've solved this by creating a typeclass `Indeterminate`, and parameterizing my polynomial type as

```
data (Ring a, Indeterminate b) => Polynomial a b
```

This approach feels perfectly natural for the `Ring` part because I *do* care about which particular ring a given polynomial is over. It feels very contrived for the `Indeterminate` part, as detailed below.

The above approach works fine, but feels contrived. Especially so this part:

```
class Indeterminate a where
    indeterminate :: a

data T = T

instance Indeterminate T where
    indeterminate = T

data S = S

instance Indeterminate S where
    indeterminate = S
```

(and so on for perhaps a few more indeterminates). It feels weird and wrong. Essentially I'm trying to demand that instances of `Indeterminate` be singletons (in [this sense](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/lightweight-dependent-typing.html#Singleton)). The feeling of weirdness is one indicator that I might be attacking this wrongly. Another is the fact that I end up having to annotate a lot of my `Polynomial a b`s since the actual type `b` often cannot be inferred (that's not strange, but is annoying nevertheless).

Any suggestions? Should I just keep on doing it like this, or am I missing something?

PS: Don't feel offended if I don't upvote or accept answers immediately. I'll be unable to check back in for a few days.

Comment: Is there a good reason for not modelling polynomials as sequences of elements of the ring or something similar (sequences of partial sums for instance) ?

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit lost here. I don't understand why you need `Indeterminate` at all. If you just want to enforce that two bs are the same, leave it in the type signature, and that's that?

Comment: @Alexandre C.: I'm doing that. But I'd like the type signature to make it meaningless to, say, add "2 + 5t" to "6s". With polynomial as sequences of ring elements, the type system (rightfully) stops me from adding a polynomial with coefficients in one ring with one with coefficients in another, but it does not distinguish on indeterminates. Now, of course, whether or not I really need indeterminates is a very valid question :-)

Comment: @sclv: The `Indeterminate` typeclass is essentially there to force the `b` to be a singleton. It's not really needed, I agree!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure this:

```
data (Ring a, Indeterminate b) => Polynomial a b
```

...is doing what you expect it to. Contexts on `data` definitions are not terribly useful--see [the discussion here](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/NoDatatypeContexts) for some reasons why, most of which amount to them forcing you to add extra annotations without actually providing many additional type guarantees.

Second, do you actually care about the "indeterminate" parameter other than to ensure that the types are kept distinct? A pretty standard way of doing that sort of thing is what's called [phantom types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Phantom_type)--essentially, parameters in the type constructor that aren't used in the data constructor. You'll never use or need a value of the phantom type, so functions can be as polymorphic as you want, e.g.:

```
data Foo a b = Foo b

foo :: Foo a b -> Foo a b
foo (Foo x) = Foo x

bar :: Foo a c -> Foo b c
bar (Foo x) = Foo x

baz :: Foo Int Int -> Foo Char Int -> Foo () Int
baz (Foo x) (Foo y) = Foo $ x + y
```

Obviously this does require annotations, but only in places where you're deliberately adding restrictions. Otherwise, inference will work normally for the phantom type parameter.

It seems to me that the above approach should be sufficient for what you're doing here--the business with singleton types is mostly about bridging the gap between more complicated type-level stuff and regular value-level computations by creating type proxies for values. This could be useful for, say, marking vectors with types that indicate their basis, or marking numeric values with physical units--both cases where the annotation has more meaning than just "an indeterminate called X".

Comment: With `-XEmptyDataDecls` you can make it so your "marker" types have no runtime representation whatsoever, eg. `data T`, and then a newline and contine your code.  This says `T` is a type with no constructors, and thus it really only means something to the type system.

Comment: Thank you! I think you got exactly what I was asking and wondering about. I didn't know about phantom types, so thanks for teaching me. The clarification about when singletons are actually used is also very enlightening, and goes right to the core of what I was having a problem with (really, did you read my mind?). (On a side note: I know that contexts on `data` definitions aren't useful - I use them to aid my thinking while writing the code, but take them out afterwards. I should have removed them before asking).

Comment: @gspr: At some point you may want to read about GADTs and related language extensions--the expressive power they offer seems like something you might find useful, allowing (among other things) contexts on data definitions that are actually meaningful.